# How to get combobox text after user enters a value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I have a wpf combobox bound to a CollectionView.  It is set so the user can edit the entry in the combobox selectionbox.  When the user types a value NOT in the list, I want to grab that value to use elsewhere but I cannot figure out how to get the text entered by the user.  Online help suggested using the Text property but there is no such property.  I'm using VS2013, Framework 4.5 and VB.

Comment: it would be good if you'll put your code

Comment: If I had code, I would have posted it.  As I noted, I could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But there exists a `Text` property ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) for the combobox. Also, to catch the event of the user editing the `ComboBox`, you should subscribe to the `TextChanged` event. I created a simple WPF with a ComboBox and added the event handler.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEditable="True" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="comboBox_TextChanged" />
```

And the function that handles the TextChanged:

```
Private Sub comboBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Text changed to: " + comboBox.Text)
End Sub
```

[image: a simple wpf example]

Comment: You're right about the text property.  I look for it and must have looked right at it and missed it.  Sorry.  Yep, that solution is what I was looking for.

Comment: Why is WPF so complicated in this case and why does the Combobox.TextInput event not fire?